# jQUery chosen library and fancybox

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox, jquery-chosen

I am using jquery chosen library in fancybox popup and have problem with fancybox height.

Please check this jsbin http://jsbin.com/ovobej/1/

Any idea to make it working fine. I can give static height for content

Comment: Please be more detailed. Would you like the height to be dynamic?

Comment: Yes. while clicking on the select box height should increase

Answer (score 0):

.fancybox-inner
{    overflow: hidden;}

Comment: hey, I want to resize fancybox

Answer (score 0):

I think what you'd like is the following: http://jsbin.com/ovobej/15/
So fancybox doesn't have to resize when clicking a 'chosen select'.
But the select box should not be 'restricted' in the fancybox frame.
By adding:

```
.fancybox-inner { overflow: visible !important; }
```

The chosen selectbox bahaves the same as the normal browser select.